# Low Search related child's category

Tags: search, low-search, related

Is it possible to search/filter based on a related child's category?

In our results page we always list the parent channel - 'courses'.

90% of the time we search for keywords and categories assigned to the course entries.

Within a course you relate a child entry from the 'course date' channel.

A 'course date' can then be categorised by location.

So when searching I want to return 'courses' where our child 'course date' location category is X.

Is this possible, and what is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box, but I have a (non-public) extension that can help you out. [Contact me](http://gotolow.com/contact) if you want to try that out.